# What's the ID nr of this SMD transistor?

Tags: surface-mount

Need to replace this transistor, SOT-23. Any ideas on ID?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's a MMBT3906, or one of the other many SMD 2N3906-alikes.

Comment: as a curiosity, how can you tell?

Comment: could it be a PMBT3906?

Comment: @WesleyLee: http://www.s-manuals.com/smd/2a

Comment: @PhilipDeSmedt: Or a FMMT3906. Or a KST3906. They're all the same part on the inside.